# use a output of class to construct a new if and else

Tags: php

i am using a `user id , friend id , page` and passing the values to a class so that it could detect that the login user can view the profile of other user based on other user's privacy setting. its such as after the values are passed to the class the query stuff takes place and i am using echo to tell if `allow` or `dont` means the output of class comes in these two words based on privacy setting . now the problem is how do i use this output to be used in a variable ?

i am passing the values into class like this

```
$error_result->check_allowed($friend_id,$id,$page);
```

now i know i get a output from that class as allow or dont . now how do i use that output further ?

Comment: Are you seriously trying to code without knowing about the `if` statement?

Comment: no i knw very well about if and else , i want to get the output data of that class in a variable thats it is that possible ?

Comment: As in $var = $error_result->check_allowed(...) ? Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: yes something like that , in that class check_allowed after all queries are run there is a output . i want to get that output in a variable

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to change check_allowed() to return a result rather than printing it's result to stdout? (I'm assuming that is what you mean).

Comment: let me try to explain it , the class check_allowed() after being called echo a word which is according to the query being run in that class that word is either "allow" or "dont" based on query results. i want that word that is being echo in that class into a variable outside the class . is that possible ?

Comment: Use the `return` statement to return back some value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `check_allowed()`, after you do the queries, you need to return a TRUE/FALSE value using `return` statement. This could be used at the caller's side.

Example:

```
// ---- function definition inside the class
function check_allowed($friend_id,$id,$page)
{
  // do some queries or whatever operation..
  if($query_succeeded)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}


//----------------- outside the class, we are calling this function..

$result = $error_result->check_allowed($friend_id,$id,$page); 
if($result == true)
{
  echo "Allowed";
}
else
{
  echo "Not allowed";
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Comment: or maybe no need to return FALSE, because `FALSE == NULL` `return false` means to return nothing.

Comment: @metal_fan it's better to explicitly return something when a function is not expected to be "void". Type coercion is nice and all but documented return values is better :)

Comment: @Jack Yeah. Return "void" means return FALSE. You can simply check that `defined('FALSE') and echo 'False is a const'` then `print FALSE`, then see if `print TRUE` == 1. By the way, you're totally right about it, BUT I just suggested it

Comment: @metal_fan I'm not sure if any of that made sense, but void is certainly not the same as false; void is nothing (although in PHP it translates to null) but false is a boolean.

Comment: @Jack `TRUE` is not actually boolean and you can check that. `<?php if ( defined('TRUE') print TRUE);` Check that. It's a full prof of the constant. The same goes for `FALSE` `<? if ( defined('FALSE') ) print 'False is a const'; ?>` .`FALSE` is the same as `NULL` . Again check that `<?php if (FALSE == NULL) { echo 'the same'; }`. Also, return `FALSE` means return nothing. `<?php function a(){return false;}  function b(){} ?>` Now compare them `<?php if ( a() == b() ){echo 'the same'; }`

Comment: @metal_fan unfortunately your proof misses one vital point: type coercion; no doubt `1 == true` and `null == false`, but `1 !== true`, `false !== null` and `false !== ""`

Comment: @Jack Yeah I know that. But I said, that both `TRUE` and `FALSE` are constants.

Comment: @metal_fan They are constants, but all constants have a type - check out `gettype(true)` vs. `gettypes(null)` - thus `return;` is not the same as `return false;`